# Two JsonArray`s Comparing missing keys

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have 2 JsonArrays with datas from API

**Api 1**

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "value":270
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "value":1432493
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "value":63
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "value":412
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "value":371
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "value":824
   },
   {
      "id":9,
      "value":266
   }
]
```

**Api 2**

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   },
   {
      "id":9,
      "name":"name",
      "description":"description"
   }
]
```

i will Cambine it to new array

```
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(API1);
            JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(API2);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray1.length();i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject json_data1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                DataWallet walletData = new DataWallet();
                if (json_data.getString("id").equals(json_data1.getString("id"))) {
                    walletData.wallet_id = json_data.getString("id");
                    walletData.textWalletNumber = json_data.getString("value");
                    walletData.wallet_name = json_data1.getString("name");
                    walletData.wallet_desc = json_data1.getString("description");

                } else {
                    walletData.wallet_id = json_data1.getString("id");
                    walletData.textWalletNumber = "0";
                    walletData.wallet_name = json_data1.getString("name");
                    walletData.wallet_desc = json_data1.getString("description");

                }
                data.add(walletData);

            }
```

Now have i the problem 
1,2,3 work fine by 4 is the problem from API1 give no entrys for value with "0" i will ad this over codes but this work not.

Comment: why not use Jackson? this will reduce your code..

Comment: it is a serialization library for Java. Please look at this tutorial on it. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/

Comment: Sry this help me not by my Problem and this reduce my code not this makes my code longer!

Answer (score 0):

You need also a second for loop inside the the first one (jArray1) to iterate over the jArray. Altogether you need two for loops to combine 2 arrays. If you have a really huge arrays its a good idea to use better algorithms e.g. Binary search. It makes it faster and more optimal for  O.

Here is how it should look like. I do not have any editor right now to test it or there can be some synax errors. The concept is right. I suggest you to learn the concept of Bobble Search and Binary Search. If you learn it you can solve any problem in this sort.

```
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(API1);
    JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(API2);

    for(int i=0;i<jArray1.length();i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<jArray.lenght();j++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject json_data1 = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
            DataWallet walletData = new DataWallet();
            if (json_data.getString("id").equals(json_data1.getString("id"))) {
                walletData.wallet_id = json_data.getString("id");
                walletData.textWalletNumber = json_data.getString("value");
                walletData.wallet_name = json_data1.getString("name");
                walletData.wallet_desc = json_data1.getString("description");
                data.add(walletData);
            } 

        }
}
```

Comment: Kannst du mir dabei helfen wie ich es am besten umsetzten kann? da ich nicht mehr weiter weiß.|
Can you help me how I can best implement it? Since I do not know any more.

Comment: Ok I write it for you tonight. Do not forget to vote for answer;)

Comment: I edited the answer. Here you go. Try it and you will find a solution for sure.

Comment: E/FEHLER: org.json.JSONException: Index 27 out of range [0..27)
This is my error

Comment: The indexes were wrong. I edited the Solution. What do you use as IDE?

Comment: I see on first momemt what this not work ! and this add not the missing keys with value 0. IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off it is bad idea to string compare id's. You should use those as int values. Same with values. Once you fix your model to support that, you should be able to use this code. There are better ways to do this using serialization libraries and OO practice, but to use the method you already are using, we can do it by comparing id's of the two lists.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(API1);
JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(API2);
for(int index_in_jArr1 = 0; index_in_jArr1 < jArray1.length(); index_in_jArr1++) {
      JSONObject json_data_jArr1 = jArray.getJSONObject(index_in_jArr1);
      int jArr1_id = json_data_jArr1.getInt("id");
      for(int index_in_jArr = 0; index_in_jArr < jArray.length(); index_in_jArr++) {
           DataWallet walletData = new DataWallet();
           JSONObject json_data_injArr = jArray1.getJSONObject(index_in_jArr);
           int jArr_id = json_data_jArr1.getInt("id");
           if(jArr1_id != jArr_id) {
                 walletData.wallet_id = json_data_jArr1.getInt("id");
                 walletData.textWalletNumber = 0;
                 walletData.wallet_name = json_data_jArr1.getString("name");
                 walletData.wallet_desc = json_data_jArr1.getString("description");
            } else {
                 walletData.wallet_id = json_data_injArr.getInt("id");
                 walletData.textWalletNumber = json_data_injArr.getInt("value");
                 walletData.wallet_name = json_data_jArr1.getString("name");
                 walletData.wallet_desc = json_data_jArr1.getString("description");
            }
            data.add(walletData);
       }
 }
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for value | This is my Error